# How to find out which port is used for web server module from Websphere's standard output log?

Tags: java, websphere, application-server

Assuming no access to production environment and no access to admin console I must find out which port is used by Websphere to listen for new http requests for REST controllers. The only entry i found is something like below:

```
webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module WebSphere ASYNC Response Servlet Application has been bound to default_host[*:8012,*:80,*:8013,*:8014,*:8015,*:443,*:9080,*:9443,*:5060,*:5061,*:8097,*:8019,*:8085].
```

Is there any other information in the standard output log that definitely state which port is web server bound to? Or maybe all mentioned ports are used?

Websphere version 8.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the log for the following messages:

```
...TCPChannel    I   TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_2 is listening on host *  (IPv6) port 9080.
...WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundDefault.
...TCPChannel    I   TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_4 is listening on host *  (IPv6) port 9443.
...WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundDefaultSecure.
```

Where `WCInboundDefault` is http port of the server and `WCInboundDefaultSecure` is https port.

Answer (score 1):

Those are *virtual* host/port combinations, the *listening* ports on any particular server will be a subset.

Looking for the message "TCPC0001I:" will at least show you actual listening ports. 
If you find an intersection with the message in your question, you have likely found the right host/port to connect to at least from the local systems perspective.

Usually the port will be quite predictable -- 9080. But colocated appservers or lots of profiles being created will result in the default web container listening port being incremented.